# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS does not save my preferences

Tags: ubuntu

From the last restart of the system, few days ago, I have a problem with setting my preferences on Ubuntu 14.04.

More precisely, I have the following issues at the boot of the system:

- Other partitions on the system are not mounted automatically. If I run `sudo fdisk -l` from the command line, only the current partition is available, but if I use GParted, other partitions are visible. Moreover, if I mount them with the command mount, they are correctly mounted.
- Sidebar icons that I lock and unlock are not maintained throughout different logins. Every time that I reboot the system, they are reset to the default.

Moreover, I'm not able to change the wallpaper of the desktop, that still remains the same, at the default.

I fear I gave some command that creates problems with ownership of files or access rights for my user.

Any idea how to solve these problems?

Answer (score 1):

Update. 
I was able to solve the problem as described here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/558446/my-dconf-gsettings-installation-is-broken-how-can-i-fix-it-without-ubuntu-reins

I ran into the terminal:

```
sudo mv /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf /etc/ld.so.conf.d/xuserlocal.conf
sudo ldconfig
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Ad 1):
For every partition, which you want to mount, you have to have line in /etc/fstab file. Please, check this file...

Ad 2)
You can repair ownership of files in home directory by this command (you have to run this command as root or with `sudo`):

```
cd /home
chown -R username.username username
```

For explanation:

```
chown - tool, which can change ownership
username.username - the first username means name of user, the second one means group.
username - the last username is name of home directory.
```

You have to replace `username` with your username.